# Xcode não encontra o botão

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

Eu criei um botão na `storyboard` para fazer a ligação a uma `viewController`.

Ao clicar no botão ocorre o erro:

> thread 1:signal SIGARBT

O que poderia estar ocasionando tal erro?

Já vi muitos tutoriais e nada.

Comment: Coloque na pergunta o código que você está utilizando para ficar mais fácil te ajudar.

Comment: Eu nao estou a usar código apenas liguei o botao á view controller....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fabio, fiz um exemplo bem simples de captura de click em um botão:

1. Criei um projeto "Single View Application"
2. No arquivo ViewController.m, implementei o callback para o click
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
3. No storyboard, adicionei o botão e cliquei com o botão direito do mouse sobre ele. Depois liguei o evento "Touch up inside" em ViewController. 
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Esse erro ocorre quando o que esta no storyboard nao esta ligado corretamente a viewcontroller. Clique com o botao direito do mouse encima no botao e veja para onde ele esta apontando. Isso vai estar no Sent Events.

Voce pode excluir a ligacao e fazer outra ou ate ligar no codigo que ja esta  na viewcontroller

Espero ter ajudado